# Auto scaling in ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

does ec2 instances have auto scaling option on by default ?
i don't want to use auto scaling if so how to protect from ec2 auto termination on scaling? 
I have enabled the termination protection already on ec2.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, your question is difficult to understand. Could you please Edit your question and provide more information about what you are trying to do, and any difficulties you are encountering. For example, are you interesting in automatically scaling the number of instances by using Auto Scaling, or do you have no interest in Auto Scaling and are you merely asking how to prevent instances from being terminated?

Comment: Actually before i had deployed my application using beanstalk with default configuration what auto scaling was doing that deleting my instance and adding a new one which was deleting my deployed code.
Then i switched to to new ec2 instance only no beanstalk and deployed my application now asking that ec2 does not have auto scaling by default and my instance wont get deleted like before ? i dont want auto scaling. I just dont want my instance to get deleted in its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon EC2 will only terminate EC2 instances if:

- Specifically requested (via the management console, [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) or an API call)
- If it was created as part of an Amazon CloudFormation stack that is being deleted/updated
- If it was created by an Auto Scaling group and:

  - The Auto Scaling group is being scaled-in, or
  - The instance is found to be unhealthy

If *you* created the instance, Auto Scaling will not touch it. Only instances created by Auto Scaling, or specifically moved into an Auto Scaling group, can be terminated by Auto Scaling.

Answer (score 0):

EC2? No. You have to go down to `Autoscaling` (in the EC2 sidebar) and set up a launch configuration to enable autoscaling. If your question was more along the lines of "how do you prevent an instance from being terminated?" then you, within your ASG configurations, adjust the [termination policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-instance-termination.html).

Comment: i was using elastic beanstalk before it was auto scaling and terminating my instance and creating new one which was losing data. 
so now i created ec2 instance to stop this that why asking.

Comment: yeah my main question was that " ec2 does not have autoscaling on by default". my instances wont get terminated for any reason.

Comment: @user3914224 - never say never.  While it is highly unlikely that your instance will be terminated you should still have backups.  And if your instance was being terminated with Elastic Beanstalk then you had it configured wrong.

Comment: @stdunbar: how to have backups and totally make it safe the ec2 instance ?